# Защита телефонов и электронных адресов от парсинга

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Добрый день!
Есть сайт написанный на php (фреймворк kohana) на котором пользователи регистрируют организации указывая их контактные телефоны и их электронные адреса.  Эта информация находиться в открытом доступе. Как защитить телефоны и адреса от парсинга роботами?

Comment: Если организация выложила в открытый доступ контактный телефон и email, то пусть парсят сколько хотят - они для этого и нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у сайта не предполагается мобильной версии тогда делайте телефоны картинками.
Которые будут подгружаться например аяксом в момент нажатия на кнопку типа посмотреть контакты. Но на 100% это не даст защиты если ваш ресурс будет очень популярен и картинки можно тоже распознать. А электропочту не показывайте а делайте форму по которой можно отправить сообщение с сайта, естественно разрешать отправлять письма по этой форме надо авторизованным и ограничивать количество писем по времени как то.

Comment: мобильная версия  есть. А есть какая нибудь либа которая картинки делает но номеру?

Comment: если есть мобильная версия тогда для того чтобы пользователь не набирал номер телефона руками, обычно номера набираются автоматом черес ссылку типа tel: и парсить будут мобильную версию после того как вы сделаете картинки на основном сайте...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php